# Capacitors phenomena

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, capacitance

I wanted to ask one simple question: when there is a uncharged capacitor directly connected to a battery with any resistance in between, does current flow in the circuit, or does it only flow until the capacitor is completely charged?

Comment: Why not look on the Internet, [charging a capacitor](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capchg.html), where everything is explained in some detail?

Answer (score 1):

Current will flow until the potential difference across the capacitor matches that of the battery. The potential difference across the capacitor therefore increases according to a negative exponential graph as charge builds up, and can be derived from the equation $\frac{V_0}{R} - \frac{Q}{RC} - \dot{Q} = 0$, where $RC$ is known as the [time constant](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/rc/rc_1.html).

Comment: The potential difference should increase exponentially, right?

Comment: It increases according to a negative exponential graph.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple answer to your one simple question:  if the voltage across a capacitor in some circuit is non-zero, there *has* been a current through the capacitor.

Further, if the voltage across a capacitor is *changing*, there *is* a current through the capacitor.